# Is there a way to have Firefox automatically bookmark a URL whenever I clip it with Evernote Web Clipper?

Tags: firefox, evernote

I use Evernote as a bookmarking tool. I think it would be useful to also save bookmarks in Firefox so that when visiting a page I can easily see if I have already bookmarked it.

Does anyone have a good solution for automating this?